# how to display android:imageView with GradientDrawable and setImageResource dynamically ?

Tags: android, imageview, selector

I want to make ImageView with specific GradientDrawable and make the `src = "@drawable/myImage"`. When I try this code I get all things fine but the `src` image doesn't display:

```
leftIcon = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.left_icon);
leftIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow333);

GradientDrawable gd=new GradientDrawable();
gd.setCornerRadii(getRandomFloatArray());
gd.setStroke(5, Color.WHITE);
gd.setColor(values[position].getColor());

GradientDrawable gd_press=new GradientDrawable();
gd_press.setCornerRadii(getRandomFloatArray());
gd_press.setStroke(5, Color.BLUE);
gd_press.setColor(values[position].getColor());

StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, gd_press );
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, gd_press);
states.addState(new int[] { }, gd);

leftIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow333);
leftIcon.setImageDrawable(states);
```

And my xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left_icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title to help people answer it faster.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you are setting a drawable `states` just right after setting image resource. If you want both the Images visible than apply one as `ImageView` background and other as a source:

```
leftIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow333);
leftIcon.setImageDrawable(states);
```

OR

```
leftIcon.setBackgroundResource(states);
leftIcon.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.arrow333);
```